Android app not connecting to local server
It's my first time creating an android app. I want to build an app that can control the media player on my pc.
What I did so far:
I'm doing this in react.I builded a web app that send commands to my server to control the media player (play, pause, etc). I ran this in the local host and works fine. So I used the same code to build the android app. I found that using capacitor I can do this.
The app opens on my device but I can't make it connect to the server. When I type the IP on my device's browser looks like the server is working.
I using websockets to do this (don't know if this is the best way).
Permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

If you need more informations just ask. Like I said its my first time doing this don't know what's relevant information.
